# Problem with subsetting of observations based on conditions R

Tags: r, dplyr

I hope you can help me with subsetting

**DATA 1**

```
df2 <- structure(
  list(
    record_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
    day_count = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), 
    event = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -40L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**MY AIM** I want to subset and mark the 5 observation days around the event (`hazard` = 1) and 5 observation days 12 days prior to the event (`hazard` = 2) by creating the `hazard` variable. See output down below:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT 1**

```
df2_output <- structure(
  list(
    record_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
    day_count = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), 
    event = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
    hazard = c(NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA)),
  row.names = c(NA, -40L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**ATTEMPT**
So I tried the following code which worked

```
test_df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(hazard = case_when(
    (day_count <= df2$day_count[df2$event == 1]) & (day_count > ((df2$day_count[df2$event == 1]) -5)) ~ 1,
    (day_count <= ((df2$day_count[df2$event == 1]) -11)) & (day_count > ((df2$day_count[df2$event == 1]) -16)) ~ 2
    )) %>%
  view()
```

**PROBLEM** However, when I try this similar idea in my main dataset, which is way larger, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `hazard`.
x Input `hazard` can't be recycled to size 553.
ℹ Input `hazard` is `case_when(...)`.
ℹ Input `hazard` must be size 553 or 1, not 82.
ℹ The error occurred in group 30: record_id = 120001.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I have already made sure that events in which you can't look back far  enough sufficiently are deleted

I have also attempted to select only 1 record_id to test the code, but I received the following error:

```
4: In day_count > ((case_series_analysis$day_count[case_series_analysis$te_yn ==  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Does anyone have a clue?

BW

Comment: `dplyr` functions expect unquoted column names, not `data$column`. If you delete all your `df2$` and just leave the column names, that will at least get you closer to working.

Comment: In addition to @GregorThomas comments, the error issue would be that you are subsetting the data `day_count <= df2$day_count[df2$event == 1])`.  The length of the subset may  be way less leading to recycling of values and it would have incorrect values.  The comparison is elementwise, so if the rhs is of different length.  it tries to recycle those values to make the lengths same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rolling sums for your test values.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
test_df2 <- df2 %>%
      group_by(record_id) %>%
      mutate( hazard = case_when(
            rollapply(event, 5, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left") >0 ~ 1,
            rollapply(event, list(11:15), sum, partial = TRUE, fill = 0) >0 ~ 2
      )
      ) %>%
      ungroup()

identical(test_df2, df2_output)
# [1] TRUE
```

added `group_by()` so an effect in one record doesn't affect another.  Since `case_when()` stops once a condition is met, a day that is 3 days before one event and 13 before a second will be coded as 1.

With thanks to @g-grothendieck for the improved code for the second rolling sum.

Comment: In place of the difference between the two rollapply's try this: `rollapply(event, list(11:15), sum, partial = TRUE, fill = 0)` The second arg specifies the offsets.